# I'm trying to dynamically move elements up and down on my webpage. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, html

I have a webpage that has a list of iframe soundcloud music "boxes" that play music and I want to add buttons to the side of these iframes to move the boxes up and down based on people voting on them. Kinda like what reddit has. (I'm doing this for fun and have no intention of publishing this) I tried absolute positioning the iframes and then using javascript to move the up or down but realized that would be a disaster to try to code.  What would be the best way of going about this? I'm relatively new to web development.

(I used bootstrap to style the webpage)

Here is the body of the html doc:

```
<body>
<div class="page-header" class="stayPut"><div class="stayPut" id="Header"><img src="logo.png" ALT="Hamiltron" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=61/></div></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron"><h1 style="text-align: center; color: white;">An Ultimate Music List.</h1></div>
    <div class="jumbotron">

            <iframe  id="box1" width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/113414910&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

            <iframe id="box2" width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/180568985&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

    <iframe id="box3" width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/161660686&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("box1").style["position"]="absolute";
document.getElementById("box1").style["top"] = "20px";
document.getElementById("box1").style["width"] = "75%";

</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A jsFiddle would useful here, or at least post some of your code.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: how do you keep track of the voting? do you use any database or this is just a html website?

Comment: It's just an html website. I'm still learning php but I'm about to try it with a database later today.

Comment: how does the voting system work? do people vote on your website or where do you get the voting numbers?

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet. I just started coding it earlier today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd love to help so I'll show you the best way I'd do it. You will need to enable voting and a database, even just a 1 table data base with values such as

```
ID | VoteCount | TRACKID
0    3           180568985
```

If I where you I'd work on this first and then assign buttons to increase the vote count in the database. I'd do this with [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to poll a [PHP file to connect to the database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) so your page doesn't reload after each vote!

Then you will need to use Javascript or get the items from the database in order when you poll them. I've created an example that will display them for you:

[Working Example of Following Code | JSFiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/2q9o5w2q/2/)

```
//This is a JSON Object that can be assessed like dataFromDatabaseExample[2].vote = 100
//NOTE THESE ARE NOT IN THE RIGHT ORDER ;)
var dataFromDatabaseExample = [{id: 0, vote: 43, songID: 113414910},
                               {id: 1, vote: 5, songID: 180568985},
                               {id: 2, vote: 100, songID: 161660686}];

//Creates an event listener to listen for if someone clicks the refresh button
$('#refresh').on('click',function(){
      refreshData();
});

//Function that holds main data that can be run whenever
function refreshData(){

   //Clears the bit of the page where the votes are going to be ie RESET
    $('#soundCloudItems').html("");

    //Sort the values to be in order using our custom sorting function compareVotes
     var songs = dataFromDatabaseExample.sort(  compareVotes  );

    //For every item we got
    for(var i=0;i<songs.length;i++){
        //Title it (Optional but shows vote count)
        $('#soundCloudItems').append("Votes: "+songs[i].vote+"<br>");
        //Display the soundcloud box
        $('#soundCloudItems').append(getSongCode(songs[i].id,songs[i].vote,songs[i].songID));
    }
}

//Run on Load to display some data
refreshData();


//TWO HELPER FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Compares two items from the array, for the vote count
function compareVotes(a,b) {
  if (a.vote > b.vote)
     return -1;
  if (a.vote < b.vote)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

//Just returns all the bulky code in a nice form as a piece of HTML/Text
function getSongCode(id,vote,SongId){
 return '<iframe data-voteCount="'+id+'" id="soundcloud'+id+'" width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/'+SongId+'&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>';
}
```

Comment: If you need any more help I'll try my best!

Comment: Very thorough answer, sir. Hat tip to you.

Comment: Vote up and check as Answer! ;D I once was where you were. :) You should look at Javascript in CodeAcadamy to learn more at this stage, it's invaluable to webAPP design and great fun!

Comment: I wish I could vote up but I don't have the reputation! Will do it in the future though. Thanks Again.